# Формы прилагательных

Tags: прилагательные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понятно, что имеется в виду. Нужно искать полную форму? Но ее же нет, как я думаю. Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

> В каком предложении прилагательное употреблено не в той форме, что в
>   остальных?

Я бы выбрал **пятое** предложение:

> *Мчат, как будто на крылах,*
>
> *Санки кони **рьяны**...*

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ.

Во всех пяти примерах имеем усечённые формы прилагательных, выполняющих синт. функцию определения.

**В первых четырёх** примерах прилагательные употреблены **в винительном** падеже,

**в пятом** же -- **в именительном** падеже.

Answer (score 0):

Полная форма есть у всех прилагательных из задания.

Может, отличается "не той формой" прилагательное *шелк**о**вы?* Которые в полной форме *шёлковые*?

См. [*шелк**о**вый*](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) как народно-поэтическое.

А возможно, следует указать на устаревшую форму [*охладелый*](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9) в значении замёрзший?

Answer (score 0):

> Не совсем понятно, что имеется в виду. Нужно искать полную форму? Но ее же нет, как я думаю. Помогите, пожалуйста

В том-то и дело, что непонятен вопрос. Знать бы что искать - и решить было бы реально. Иное - гадание на кофейной гуще. slava1947 даёт, пожалуй, единственное сколько-нибудь осмысленное понимание вопроса: разные падежи, разные грамматические функции. Но **форма**-то у них одна. Так что тут что-то перемудрили с формулировкой. Или мы все не видим чего-то простого.

Comment: форма слова -грамматическая форма, т.е.языковые средства, служащие для выражения грамматических значений. У прилагательного это не только полная и краткая формы, но и формы рода, числа, падежа. Слава прав, разные падежи - разные формы.

Comment: Подождите, Людмила, разве я возражаю против изменения по падежам? Такое ощущение, что вы с кем-то другим спорите. Я другое говорю, что ***форма*** тут одна. Краткие прилагательные вообще крайне редко используются в формах, отличных от формы именительного (только в архаике),  в уж для множественного числа это просто невозможно, я даже гипотетическую парадигмы для такой штуки наверняка не назову. Нет добров молодцев? Иду к к дорбам молодцам? Вместе с добры молодцы (*или молодцами - тут вообще аут, как согласовать архаичную форму инструметалиса с современной флексией существительного?*)?

Comment: Вот я о чем. А то, что Слава в грамматике разобрался, я и не сомневался, я ему за то отплюсовал. У меня тот же ход мыслей был, но я решил, что не стоит его писать, ибо ответ все равно не от того вопроса.

Comment: Здесь нет кратких прилагательных, все формы"усечённые", потому что являются определениями, на что Слава и указал. Потому я и говорю, что он прав, сказав, что это усечённые формы прилагательных в вин. пад., а 5-в им.п.

Comment: Ну, Людмила, это уже терминологический спор. Попытка дать контекстно-зависимое определение самого понятия "формы" через грамматическую  ***в принципе*** противоречива. Форма - это форма, а то, чем является - это содержание. )))  Ну это ладно, в другой раз. Посмотрите, Вы же сами себе противоречите. Если по вашему все формы - усеченные, то почему они разные? Опять через грамматическую роль? *В узком смысле под формой понимается одно из регулярных видоизменений грамматической единицы как представителя определенного класса.* - Грамматика.

Comment: Каким образом здесь можно увидеть ***разные*** форм при одном регулярном изменении - не представляю. Вы будете возражать против тезиса, что форма (пусть будет "усеченная", хотя не вижу зачем сущности плодить, когда есть "краткая", не украинский язык чай, где эти вещи реально различаются) - что усеченная форма для именительного и винительного падежей **не различается**?

Comment: behemothus, что-то в Ваших словах есть. Попробую подойти с другой стороны…  Словоформы _подблюдны, тесовы, шелковы, охладелы_ можно, наверное, было бы назвать усечёнными формами  прилаг. **И.-В. п. мн. ч.** Так сказать про "рьяны", похоже, невозможно: это прилагательное **вряд ли может сочетаться с неодуш. сущ.** ->

Comment: -> В сочетаниях же с одушевлёнными в В. п. при усечении конечного слога  у "рьяных" получим скорее форму "рьян", но никак не "рьяны": _рьян коней_  (по Винокуру: усечения "употребляются лишь в тех падежах, где они слогом короче членных форм"). Т. е. "рьяны" можно было бы охарактеризовать  как усечённую форму  прилаг. **И. п. мн. ч.** (но никак не **И.-В. п. мн. ч.**, как у первых четырёх прилагательных). Может, я и ошибаюсь...

Answer (score 0):

Термин "форма слова" для прилагательных имеет **два значения**: 1) существуют краткая и полная форма прилагательных; 2) полные прилагательные изменяются по падежам и числам, то есть полное прилагательное может иметь различные  словоформы.

Краткие формы в современном языке не склоняются, их синтаксическая функция - именная часть сказуемого или обособленное определение. Но  данном случае (в поэтической речи) они являются определениями, поэтому используются две их **формы**, соответствующие  И.п. и В.п.

Соответственно, пятый пример (И.п.) отличается от остальных примеров (В.п.).

Comment: *Термин "форма слова" для прилагательных имеет два значения:* - оба неверно. Начнем с того, что такому термину вообще никто не дает отдельного определения, тем более сразу двух. Он считается самодостаточным. И означает, слово, подверженное грамматическому изменению (склонению, спряжению, изменению по родам и числам, видовременному и т.д.) - в одном из таких состояний. Есть другое, "форма прилагательного"  - это несколько другое, но и оно означает только краткую или полную формы. Не надо фантазировать там, шде все извесьно и описано.

Comment: "Термин "грамматическая форма" имеет как узкое, таки широкое содержание. В широком смысле - это любой знак, выражающий грамматическое значение.  В узком смысле - это одно из видоизменений грамматической единицы как представителя определенного класса". (Из Грамматики-80). Да что там Грамматика-80,  словоформы дети в начальной школе проходят. Например, длинный - длинного - длинному - это всё формы прилагательного, причем форма "длинный" - это его начальная форма .

Comment: Вы бы хоть иногда в книжку какую заглядывали, прежде чем свои минусовки расставлять. Где Ваш ответ на вопрос? Да вот же он:  "... тут что-то перемудрили с формулировкой".  Да нет, не перемудрили, только вопрос непрост оказался,  рассчитан на наблюдательных и умеющих думать людей.

Comment: Да, кажется, Вам уже раньше меня указали на то, что здесь две формы, а не одна, как Вы утверждали. Как раз в двух формах и заключен смысл вопроса - не каждый догадается, что это так.

Comment: Sergey, обожаю читать про "про посмотреть в книжки". Как правило дальше выясняется, что автор подобных советов просто не понимает, что именно там надо смотреть.

Comment: *Термин "грамматическая форма"*  - вот и пишите "грамматическая форма", если Вы об этом.  Впрочем, все равно оба ваших определения ни к черту не годятся.

Comment: Дале из вашего источника: *В узком смысле под формой понимается одно из регулярных видоизменений грамматической единицы как представителя определенного класса. Таковы, например, формы слов той или иной части речи, составляющие их парадигмы, или формы простого предложения, составляющие парадигму предложения.* - вот это определение, которое я пытался вам растолковать. Что у него общего с вашим?! И с вашим ответом.